Explicit formula for $\check{H}^1(\mathcal{U}, F) \rightarrow coker(G(X) \rightarrow H(X))$ for Cech cohomology.
$\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$
Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{U} = (U_i)_{i \in I}$ be an open cover. Let $F$ be a sheaf of abelian groups, and embed it into a flasque sheaf $G$. Let $H$ be $coker(F \ra G)$, so we have an exact sequence $0 \ra F \ra G \ra H \ra 0$
Since $G$ is flasque, $H^1(X, G) = 0$, so the long exact sequence of derived functor cohomology goes $... \ra G(X) \ra H(X) \ra H^1(X, F) \ra 0$. Thus, we can identify $H^1(X, F) = coker(G(X) \ra H(X))$.
By Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, lemma 3.4.4, there is a map $\check{H}(\mathcal{U}, F) \ra H^1(X, F)$. Is there a nice description of this? A representative of $s \in \check{H}(\mathcal{U}, F)$, is a collection $(s_{ij}) \in \prod_{i, j} F(U_i \cap U_j)$ such that $s_{ij} + s_{jk} = s_{ik}$. I want to somehow turn these $s_{ij}$ into an element of $coker(G(X) \ra H(X))$.
I tried following the proof of lemma 4.4 and the long exact sequence, but I didn't get a nice formula. Is it possible to describe this map using a diagram chase or something, that will give a nice formula?

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but my guess would be no (of course, I cannot prove there is no "nice" formula). The reason is that Hartshorne is really using the injectivity (of his chosen injective resolution) to produce the map $\check{H}^1(F) \rightarrow H^1(F)$, and not flasqueness directly. Moreover, the fact that $\mathrm{coker}( G(X) \rightarrow H(X)) = H^1(F)$ uses the fact that flasques are $\Gamma$-acyclic, whose proof (if I recall correctly) uses Zorn's lemma. So already we have two highly non-explicit identifications.
Moreover, the map comes from the Cech-to-derived functor spectral sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech-to-derived_functor_spectral_sequence, (more precisely the filtration on the $\infty$-page), and it feels to me that it will be something highly non-explicit.
